# How to show discount on all products without applying it in checkout page

Tags: magento2, discount

I want to show X percent discount on all products in my website. I dont want to apply that on checkout page. Just only want to show visually like below image [image]

Is there any way to show this ?

Actually my problem is when i apply site wide discount from catalog price rules after that if we apply coupon code then it discounts the discounted product (with catalog price rule) on checkout page. how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So you actually want to create a banner like percentage on each product but the price will remain the same?

You can add a custom html element to your

> /app/design/frontend/{theme}/{package}/catalog/template/product/list.phtml

and

> /app/design/frontend/{theme}/{package}/catalog/template/product/view.phtml

something like:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $_product->getTypeId() !== "simple") : ?>
<?php $finalPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue(); ?>
<?php $bundleRegularPrice = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue(); ?>
<?php $save = $bundleRegularPrice - $finalPrice; ?>
<?php $percent = round(($save * 100) / $bundleRegularPrice); ?>
<?php if ($percent) : ?>
    <span class="product-label sale-label"><span>-<?php echo $percent; ?>%</span></span>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

on the right spot of each page, i.e the product image banner probably. Please feel free to adjust the code as needed.

Comment: please check my updated question